# How to include random list element in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a variable `questionchoice = ['one', 'two', 'three']` and want a random element of it to be included in a template.

I tried `{% include 'questions/question-'{{ questionchoice|random }}'.html' %}` but it doesn't work.

Any help, please?

EDIT:

I modified my variable to include the whole link:

`questionchoice = ['questions/question-one.html', 'questions/question-two.html', 'questions/question-three.html']`

After that I used this in my template:

```
{% with questionchoice|random as question %}
    {% include question %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a template filter for that argument with the include template tag. You can move that logic into your view method:

views.py

```
import random
def view(request):
    return render(request, {
        "question_template": "questions/question-{}.html".format(random.randint(1,3)),
    })
```

template

```
{% include question_template %}
```